# what will happen if I miss shutdown clause after declaring ExecutorService in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Currently I am working on threading jobs using the `ExecutorService` class and the `newFixedThreadPool` command in Java. 
When I forgot to execute the `shutdown()` command after declaring the `ExecuterService` instance, my program never turned off. 
I guessed that `ExecuterService` may have an internal command shutting down its threads, since it implements the `Executor` interface which doesn't have explicit `shutdown()` commands. 
I am wondering what happens inside the `ExecutorService` class and related threads, such as when the threads will be dead, and what will happen the `shutdown()` command is forgotten. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool` creates a thread pool with the given number of "core" threads, which are never shut down until the `shutdown()` method is called on the thread pool.

Look at the [`finalize` method of `ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#1436) (the concrete class returned by a call to [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java/#88)):

```
protected void finalize() {
  shutdown();
}
```

So, if the `ExecutorService` instance becomes eligible for garbage collection, it will be shutdown when `finalize()` is called.

However, as with all things related to the `finalize()` method, you shouldn't rely upon this being called at any particular time (if at all).

Comment: worth adding, it will keep `poll()`ing it's underlying queue

Comment: Thank you Andy! its so helpful

Answer (score 0):

[newFixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))
 **The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.**
So unless you call shutdown () explicitly there is very little chance of executor service object being eligible for garbage collection, Thread might still have the reference of the executor .
 JVM by default shutdown all threads which belong to the main thread pool only.